# SAML 2 SSO AUTH COOKIE ID MOVE TO DISTRIBUTED with itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Tags: redis, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Using the ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2, is there any way to keep the cookie information in Redis, If the pod is destroyed the session will not be there so any solution?

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.NET Core you can implement the ITicketStore and configure it in ConfigureServices on the AddSaml2 method, like this:

```
services.AddSaml2(sessionStore: RedisTicketStore);
```

The ITicketStore provides an abstract storage mechanic to preserve identity information on the server while only sending a simple identifier key to the client. This is most commonly used to mitigate issues with serializing large identities into cookies.